# Vista/Win7 Delphi Audio device information

Tags: delphi, audio, windows-vista

is there a way to get all Audio device names with delphi(D2009) on Vista or Win 7, I managed to get the number of devices, and to get the device PropertyStore using IMMDevice, but I wasnt able to go forward :|

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ask the `PropertyStore` for the [`PKEY_DeviceInterface_FriendlyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316587%28VS.85%29.aspx) (look at Windows SDK to get the value)

Comment: I was using this key but I didn't declared it as it should :) This is the right declaration if someone find it helpfull:

PKEY_Device_FriendlyName: TPropertyKey = (fmtid: (D1:$a45c254e; D2:$df1c ; D3:$4efd; D4: ($80, $20, $67, $d1, $46, $a8, $50, $e0)); pid: 14);