# Windows: get default microphone name

Tags: python, windows, audio, portaudio

In python2.7 on Windows, I need to get the name of the default microphone, which will be a string such as "Microphone (2- High Definition Audio Device)".

My first attempt was to query WMI using subprocess: `wmic path Win32_SoundDevice get * /format:list`. Unfortunately, this seems to return speakers as well as mics, and I can't see any property that would let me distinguish the two. Also, the name of the correct device is not in the right format, e.g. it appears as simply "High Definition Audio Device" instead of the full correct string "Microphone (2- High Definition Audio Device)".

My second attempt was to use PyAudio (the python bindings to PortAudio). Calling `PyAudio().get_default_input_device_info()["name"]` gets me pretty close, but unfortunately the name is getting truncated for some reason! The return value is "Microphone (2- High Definition " (truncated to 31 characters length). If I could only get a non-truncated version of this string, it would be perfect.

Any ideas for what is the simplest, most self-contained way to get the default microphone name? Thanks!

Comment: related to the truncation problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429143/get-the-full-audio-device-name-from-windows

Answer (score 2):

In my experience with PortAudio, names of MME devices are truncated to 32 characters.  It has always been my assumption that this behavior is specific to the WMME API.  You should be able to query information about the same physical device in other APIs like DirectSound or WASAPI.  (In C/C++ this requires that PortAudio be configured to compile with WASAPI and/or DirectSound.)  If you query the same physical device as a WASAPI or DirectSound device, all characters of a devices name are accessible.  You should be able to do this by getting the default device name and then searching for another device that matches it.

The python code to obtain the name of the default DirectSound input device should look something like this:

```
deviceIndex = get_host_api_info_by_type(paDirectSound)["defaultInputDevice"]
deviceName = get_device_info_by_index(deviceIndex)["name"]
```

Comment: Thanks! If you are able to please provide a python code example that queries the default mic name from DirectSound or WASAPI, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I can get the full string from ffmpeg, as follows:

`ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

And then the name of the mic will be on the line after "DirectShow audio devices"

Comment: Actually, this doesn't always work. It worked on a Windows 8 tablet, but on a Windows 7 desktop, it just returned the truncated string.

Comment: dshow always seems truncated, hopefully there's some other way to enumerate them instead...