# NAudio.Mixer clip device name

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

My sound card name is `Динамики(Realtek High Definition Audio)`. And NAudio.Mixer clip this name to `Динамики(Realtek High Definiti`. What I need to do, to name of device will be full?

Comment: It seems that NAudio just wraps around the mixerGetDevCaps windows call. This seems to have a hardcoded length see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757291(v=vs.85).aspx. So in other words no I don't think so. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429143/get-the-full-audio-device-name-from-windows

Comment: @TheKingDave If I understand you correctly, You think that I cant use NAudio.Mixer library to know full device name?

Comment: This is a windows common issue - you will have to dig into DirectSound to get full device name.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor I cant using DirectSound :(. I write program to Windows Embedded and in that not install DirectX :(

Comment: @EXTRAM Yes from what I've seen the NAudio.Mixer Library cannot pick-up the full name. Windows is hard-coded to 30 characters

Comment: Sorry for bad news, but I guess you won't be getting any resolution there.  BTW, why full name?